# BizTalk Flat file parsing Unexpected end of stream while looking for:','

Tags: biztalk

I have a CSV file that needs to be disassembled into XML.

It's a normal looking CSV with a header for first row followed by repeating records. The rows are delimited by CR+LF and the columns are delimited by commas. It does contain lots of columns so rather than pasting here, I've added a link to the sample I'm using for testing: [Input CSV file](http://biztalkers.com/stackoverflow/ff-dis/Init4PO.csv). A copy of the flat-file XSD can be found here: [Flat file schema](http://biztalkers.com/stackoverflow/ff-dis/PurchaseOrder_FF.xsd)

Within visual studio, I can right-click the schema, select "Validate Instance" and this works file, producing the following xml document:[XML document](http://biztalkers.com/stackoverflow/ff-dis/PurchaseOrder_FF_output.xml)

I've created a receive pipeline, into which I've added a flat-file disassemble component. The DocumentSpecName property has been set to the strong name for the flat file schema.

My problem is, when the sample CSV is processed by the pipeline, I get the following error in the event log:

*Reason: Unexpected end of stream while looking for:
','
The current definition being parsed is PO. The stream offset where the error occured is 2018. The line number where the error occured is 4. The column where the error occured is 0.*

Can anyone see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by removing the Header node from the schema. I then set the "HeaderSpecName" property of the receive pipeline to point to the same schema as "DocumentSpecName" and ensured that the "PreserveHeader" property was set to false (default).

I realise that the BizTalk docs suggest creation of separate schema for Header and Body but I don't see the value in this if the structure of the header and body records are identical.

I have created many FF schemas in the past with a Header node. I prefer to have this because it better describes the structure of the FF that is to be disassembled. My standard technique is to simply omit to map the record to the canonical schema after disassembly.

I can't explain why disassembly was failing on this occasion but time is pressing so I'd better move on.